# How to read specific columns using dropna(thresh)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image: Dataframe picture]

How do I drop columns which have 3 missing values from Q1 - Q8.
Following which, for Q1 - Q8, if there are 2 or less missing value, to input default value as "0".

I have tried various forms of dropna(thresh=N) but I am not sure if it can read specific columns only.

Comment: have you tried using `subset` argument? `dropna(thresh=N, subset=[Q1,...,Q8])`

Comment: Yup I did.. maybe I was doing it wrong, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is :

Split your dataset in 2 datasets :

```
df_no_change = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
df_change = df[['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8']]
```

Then apply the column removal to `df_change`

```
df_change = df_change.dropna(thresh=len(df_change) - 2, axis=1)
```

And finally re concatenate your dataframes

```
df = pd.concat([df_change, df_no_change], axis=1)
```

This may work

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't hesitate accepting the offer if that solved the problem.